# Railroad diagrams for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, grammar

Anyone knows a book or a web-site that would feature a simple set of railroad diagrams for Haskell grammar?

Something like this but in English:

http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/pub/FP/CourseLiterature/haskellsyntax-main.pdf

"Simple" is the key word here. Formal BNFs are too cryptic to be used as a cheat sheet.

Comment: The Haskell report contains a highly detailed and compact representation of Haskell's syntax, albeit in BNF:  http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html

Comment: There are several tools for converting BNF specifications of grammars to syntax (railroad) diagrams. If you can't find the diagrams you're looking for, I would suggest writing or using a pre-written conversion algorithm to generate the diagram form the Haskell BNF specification.

Answer (score 3):

There is some BNF in the Haskell 2010 report (especially in the "Syntax" chapter):

http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/

Note that most programs use language extensions which add syntax to the base Haskell language - e.g. the FunctionalDependencies extension. Also, GHC has added new syntax (most recently lambda-case / lambda-if). A list of syntactic extensions supported by GHC 7.6 (currently the latest) is available at:

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html